# link making GET (rather than DELETE) request to wrong controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a link in views/questions/show.html.erb that lets users delete tags.

```
 <%=link_to "x",
:remote => true,
:url => remove_question_tag_path(@question, tag),
:method => :delete,
:html => { :id => "delete-#{tag.name.parameterize}"} %>

<% end %>
```

The remove_question_tag_path route is created by nesting the tags resource inside the questions resource.

```
 resources :questions do 
    resources :answers do 
      member { post :vote }
      end
      resources :tags do
          member do 
            delete :remove
          end 
      end
  end
```

Rake routes shows that this route exists as I try to use it in the url

```
remove_question_tag DELETE /questions/:question_id/tags/:id/remove(.:format)               tags#remove
```

However, when I click on the link, it's making a get request to the show action of the Questions controller, rather than the remove action of the Tags controller, as rake routes indicates is the destination for the route.

```
Started GET "/questions/25?html%5Bid%5D=delete-outdoors&method=delete&url=%2Fquestions%2F25%2Ftags%2F2%2Fremove" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-26 19:01:00 -0700
```

Can you explain what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%= link_to "x", remove_question_tag_path(@question, tag), :remote => true, :method => :delete, :html => { :id => "delete-#{tag.name.parameterize}"} %>
```

Explanation: you do not specify url for link so `link_to` makes a hash of all given arguments except `"x"` and treats them as url options. Therefore, `:method` option is just added to `GET` parameters instead of generating `DELETE` request.